# Does Apache allow 2 modules to handle the same HTTP request?

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

Some of my HTTP requests are not simple file requests. They require some sort of computation at Server side. Can I configure Apache to pass those request to a PHP script first then a fastcgi module, and collect the response from the fastcgi module and send back to the client?

By default, a request (eg. https://www.example.com/cgi/fcgi/SpecialProcessing/abc/def will be directly routed to the fast cgi module). Anyway to make this request to a PHP handler first then the fast cgi module?

Thank you.
Angela